# SQL Converting an INSERT SELECT to UPDATE as well

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some SQL written up to address my problem but it is not quite ready. I have been attempting different queries for days now without much luck. FYI I inherited this DB so it may be a bit more advanced than what I am used to.

There is a many-to-many relationship between Formula and Color using the bridge table FormulaColor. FormulaColor has the columns (FormulaId, ColorId, Percentage).

My Business problem, we are converting all the formulas that use color A with the colors B(1%), C(2.8%) and D(96.2%). So if a Formula currently uses the color A as 50% of the formula then I would add a row for that formula with the B color and a percentage of .5%, a row for C color with a percentage of 1.4% and a row for D color with a percentage of 48.1%.

The problem though, is a given formula that contains color A, may also already contain one or more of colors B, C or D. In that case I need to update the percentage by simply adding what was calculated above.

The actual sql that I have so far is as follows. *Note that this is just for handling 1 of the new colors (ColorId=2594)

```
INSERT INTO FormulaColor (FormulaId, ColorId, Percentage) 
SELECT FormulaId, 2594 as ColorId, round((.01*FormulaColor.Percentage),2) as Percentage
FROM FormulaColor WHERE ColorId=2595;
DELETE FROM FormulaColor WHERE ColorId = 2595;
```

I was thinking that using the upsert method that uses @@rowscount is what I need? If so, I can't figure out how to do the update to just add the calculated amount to the percentage.

Any help or resources is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I ended up using the solution from Andriy M. In case it helps someone else out I am posting the actual SQL that I used.

```
DECLARE @DeletedColor int;
DECLARE @Replacement TABLE (ColorId int, Percentage float);

-- old ColorId getting replaced
SET @DeletedColor = 2595

-- new ColorId's and the percentages needed to recalculate
INSERT INTO @Replacement (ColorId, Percentage) VALUES (2594, .01)
INSERT INTO @Replacement (ColorId, Percentage) VALUES (2521, .028)
INSERT INTO @Replacement (ColorId, Percentage) VALUES (2533, .962)

SELECT
  fc.FormulaId,
  r.ColorId,
  Percentage = round(fc.Percentage * r.Percentage, 2)
INTO #FormulaColor
FROM FormulaColor fc
CROSS JOIN @Replacement r
WHERE fc.ColorId = @DeletedColor
;

UPDATE old
SET old.Percentage = old.Percentage + new.Percentage
FROM FormulaColor old
INNER JOIN #FormulaColor new
 ON old.FormulaId = new.FormulaId
AND old.ColorId   = new.ColorId
;

INSERT INTO FormulaColor (FormulaId, ColorId, Percentage)
SELECT new.FormulaId, new.ColorId, new.Percentage
FROM #FormulaColor new
LEFT JOIN FormulaColor old
 ON old.FormulaId = new.FormulaId
AND old.ColorId   = new.ColorId
WHERE old.FormulaId IS NULL
;

DELETE FROM FormulaColor WHERE ColorId = @DeletedColor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `@DeletedColor` be the ID of the colour to delete, and `@Replacement` the table of the replacement colours, declared like this:

```
DECLARE @DeletedColor int;
DECLARE @Replacement TABLE (ColorId int, Percentage float);
```

One way to approach the problem would be like this:

1. Prepare the actual colour values to add to every formula:

   ```
   SELECT
     fc.FormulaId,
     r.ColorId,
     Percentage = fc.Percentage * r.Percentage
   INTO #FormulaColor
   FROM FormulaColor fc
   CROSS JOIN @Replacement r
   WHERE fc.ColorId = @DeletedColor
   ;
   ```

   This is creating a list of replacement colours for every formula containing the `@DeletedColor`. The percentage specified for every replacement colour in the replacement table is factored by the percentage of each formula's `@DeletedColor` to form the final percentage for the replacement colour.
2. Update existing `FormulaColor` colours from the just created row set:

   ```
   UPDATE old
   SET old.Percentage = old.Percentage + new.Percentage
   FROM FormulaColor old
   INNER JOIN #FormulaColor new
    ON old.FormulaId = new.FormulaId
   AND old.ColorId   = new.ColorId
   ;
   ```
3. Insert the colours from the new row set to the formulas that do not contain those colours:

   ```
   INSERT INTO FormulaColor (FormulaId, ColorId, Percentage)
   SELECT new.FormulaId, new.ColorId, new.Percentage
   FROM #FormulaColor new
   LEFT JOIN FormulaColor old
    ON old.FormulaId = new.FormulaId
   AND old.ColorId   = new.ColorId
   WHERE old.FormulaId IS NULL
   ;
   ```

Naturally, since you are modifying the actual table using more than one statement, it would be best to carry out the modifications in a transaction to ensure their atomicity.

Comment: I had to do some research to understand a lot of what was happening and how to use this such as how to set @DepletedColor. However it seems to have worked just fine in the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReplacementInfo](
[OldColorId] [int] NULL,
[NewColorID] [int] NULL,
[Percentage] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

```
Declare @KillColor int
Select @KillColor=1

Select FormulaId 
into #tmp
from dbo.FormulaColor 
where ColorId=@KillColor

Select t1.FormulaId,Coalesce(FC.ColorId,RI.NewColorID) as ColorID,Coalesce(FC.Percentage*RI.Percentage,RI.Percentage) as Percentage
into #tmpInsert
from dbo.ReplacementInfo RI
join #tmp t1 on 1=1
left join dbo.FormulaColor FC on FC.ColorId=RI.NewColorID and t1.FormulaId=FC.FormulaId


Delete FormulaColor  
from #tmpInsert
where #tmpInsert.FormulaId=FormulaColor.FormulaId and #tmpInsert.ColorId=FormulaColor.ColorId

Delete FormulaColor  where ColorId=@KillColor

insert into FormulaColor
Select * from #tmpInsert

Drop Table #tmp
Drop Table #tmpInsert
```

Comment: A side note: `join #tmp t1 on 1=1` is equivalent to `cross join #tmp t1` (just thought I'd let you know in case you weren't aware).

Comment: Thanks I will test this out in the next couple of days and if it works mark your answer!